# Is there an FTP client for Windows 7 with a text-based UI? (not text-prompt based, like ftp.exe)

Tags: windows-7, ftp

Is there such as thing as a text-mode FTP client for Windows 7 ?

By 'text-mode' I mean one that runs in a CMD.EXE window as opposed to a Windows GUI application.

It also needs to be something along the lines of FileZilla, i.e. menu-driven as opposed to command-entry clients like NcFTP or indeed the built-in one.

*edit:*

To avoid confusion, what I mean is an application similar to that pictured (ZTreeWin File Manager), which runs from CMD.EXE and uses text characters for its UI, within the CMD.EXE window.

The built-in FTP client, and things like NcFTP offer a prompt at which you issue commands. That's not what I'm looking for.

[image: ZTreeWin Screenshot]

Comment: Text mode means something completely different when it comes to FTP. You are looking for a command line FTP client.

Comment: Why exactly would you prefer an ancient GUI over a modern Windows GUI? It's still a GUI you want, so I'm trying to get the point here. Maybe there are other solutions we can think of if we know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_(Client) ? also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073211/filezilla-client-run-in-command-line

Comment: I was wanting to run it via Windows Remote Shell, and I am presuming/hoping that it would have multiple transfer capability, resume capability etc that prompt-based FTP wouldn't have.

Comment: What you're looking for is a CLI FTP Client. CLI stands for Command Line Interface, rather than GUI, graphical user interface.

Comment: note that Microsoft indows `ftp.exe` also runs in `cmd.exe`. `text-mode` is a video mode that happens when you go to fullscreen with e.g. `alt`+`enter` in `cmd.exe` in windows **xp**. vista and 7 has this feature removed, however supposedly there are hacks that can restore it, like disabling your video display driver (***warning***: you may not be able to turn it back on if you have a digital-only connection, or something goes wrong, so ***do not do this unless you know how can you turn it back in safe-mode or something***)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [FAR Manager](http://www.farmanager.com). It's a free (and open source) orthodox file manager with textual user interface for Windows.

Comment: That seems to have some form of FTP capability, I'll take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 has a built-in command line FTP client called `ftp`.

Syntax: [List of FTP commands for the Microsoft command-line FTP client](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm)

Comment: I know all about the default client, thanks! See my edited question which was maybe unclear.